# _wsopen_s with _O_U8TEXT flag, returns 0 to buffer, inbetween chars, and 4 inbetween russian chars. VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++-2010

If I input a UTF-8 encoded file like,

example.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>Текст на русском</title>
```

Where "Текст на русском" - Is text in russian

```
#include <string>
#include <ios>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
int main () 
{
int fl; unsigned int nbytes = 60000,bspr; char buf [60000];
errno_t err = _wsopen_s(&fl,L"c:\\example.html", _O_U8TEXT,_SH_DENYNO,_S_IREAD | _S_IWRITE ); // &fh,"c:\\example.html",_O_RDONLY, 
if ( err!=0 ) exit (1);
if ((bspr = _read(fl,buf,nbytes))<=0 )
{
    perror (" Error opening file ");
    exit (1);
}

}
```

I get buf[0]=60 '<', buf[1]=0, buf[2]=104 'h',buf[3]=0, and so on

until i reach russian letters, then i get totally improper symbols like 20 '' each followed by 4 '',

'char' - is the vstudio output of this character .. strangely same for 20 and 4.

So the question is - Is there any way I can get output buffer to a string till EOF, formatted properly , even if not using this operator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `_O_U8TEXT` causes `_read` to convert from UTF-8 to UTF-16. You should probably be reading using high-level Unicode functions like [`getwc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5231d02a%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) when opening a stream in a unicode mode. You could use [`_wfopen_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with `L"rt, ccs=UTF-8"`, or if you need the sharing support you could use your existing `_wsopen_s` call followed by [`_wfdopen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dye30d82%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).